# Convert 2d array to 1d array for drawing line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx, directx-9

As LPD3DXLINE only accepts 1D, I convert 2d array to 1d array. So, I can keep the drawn line on the screen and draw another new line.

```
D3DXVECTOR2 lineVertices[newLine][currentLine]

for (int i=0; i < noOfNewLine; i++)
    line->Draw(lineVertices[i], 2, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0));
```

If I change to

```
D3DXVECTOR2 lineVertices[currentLine][newLine]
```

How should I do with

```
lineVertices[i]
```

to convert it to 1d array successfully?

Answer (score 1):

why do you need to convert 2d in 1d? Any array in C\C++ is stored in the memory as 1d allready.
Just assign the adress of the first elemnt to a pointer

```
p = &lineVectices[0][0];
```

where `p` is a pointer to your array type.
And then iterate across `p`

```
for (int i=0; i<newLine*currentLine; i++){
// do stuff with p[i]
}
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'D3DXVECTOR2 (*)[2]' to 'D3DXVECTOR2 *'

Comment: @optimisez sorry, edited my answer, it should be `p = &lineVectices[0][0]`